# How to make a Textbox editable on click and add a button to the side Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to add a feature just like stack overflow comments where clicking on the edit link the div transforms to a text box and we get a submit button .

But the problem is i have multiple comments which i am populating via ngFor how do i remove the property readonly from the selected div in which the edit has been clicked .

This is what i have tried.

```
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="email" class="tab-pane active">
            <div *ngFor="let i of comments; let index = index" [@flyInOut]>
                <div class="well">
                    <input type=”text” value="{{i.comment}}" [readonly]="false" /><span>
                        Edited <time>{{today | amDifference: i.createdAt :'minutes'
                            : false}}</time> before
                    </span><a><i
                        class="align remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"
                        (click)="edit(index)"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also i would love to have something like checking time i have already done the backend part of same how to only enable the edit button for the comment where the amDifference is less than 5 mins and then we show a delete option.

Comment: PrimeNG has a directive for this. Take a look at their source code on GitHub: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/inplace

Comment: @ThinkingMedia is there anything we can build on our own instead of using primeNG

Comment: If we go for something like this we cannot enable or disable at the time factor right i was thinking of building something like this any idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngIf-Else](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else) to provide a second template to show like such:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="email" class="tab-pane active">
        <div *ngFor="let i of comments; let index = index" [@flyInOut]>
            <div *ngIf="i.editMode; else editBlock" class="well">
                <!-- Show stuff here -->
                <a>
                    <i class="align remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"
                       (click)="i.editMode=true">
                    </i>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ng-template #editblock>
                <div class="well">
                    <!-- Edit stuff here -->
                    <input type="button" (click)="i.editMode=false" value="Done"/>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As all of it is wrapped around a div. Clicking on the edit button will it edit all text box ? Also if i need to check time and disable the edit button although i dnt think we can accommodate that here

Comment: I'm unsure of what result you are looking for here but there are multiple ways you can show/hide, include/exclude or enable/disable DOM element, whether they are containers for other elements, inputs, buttons or any other type of elements. You can use *ngIf to include or not an element on your DOM (basically a show/hide but allows to avoid rendering elements if they aren't needed on page load). You can use [disabled]="true/false" to disable or enable an element using angular data binding. [readonly] works as well, you simply need to provide it with the data that you have in your 'comments'